# Why does the inclusion: ${PP}^n\to {RP}^{\infty}$ induce the isomorphism on cohomologies with coefficient $Z_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why does the inclusion: $\mathbb{R}P^n\to \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$, induce an isomorphism on the cohomology groups $H^i$ with coefficients in $Z_2$ for any $i\le n$? It's not obvious to me, can you give some ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{RP}^n$? Also, please add some context. Where did you see this stated?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  It's on Hatcher's textbook, at the end of theorem3.19

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese and he just stated the same words...

Comment: You can for example use CW complex structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cohomology of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is given by homology of the cocomplex, $\dots \to Hom(C^n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))\to \dots$, where $C^n$ is the free abelian group of on cells of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb{R}P^n$. The inclusion $\mathbb{R}P^n\to \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ is an isomorphism on the cells in dimension $\le n$, so that the induced map on cochain complexes is just truncation at the $(n+1)$st place. This implies that it is an isomorphism in degrees $<n$. In this case though, all of the differnetials are zero, since $Hom(C^n, \mathbb{Z}/(2)=\mathbb{Z}/(2)=H^n(\mathbb{R}P^n)$, so that it is infact an isomorphism in dimension $n$ also.